# Mouseposition Tooltips, (Tippy, Tooltip.js) on Fullcalendar

Tags: node.js, meteor, fullcalendar, popper.js, tippyjs

i implemented Tippy (https://atomiks.github.io/tippyjs/)  as a Tooltip library for Fullcalendar (https://fullcalendar.io/)

I have this in the eventRender function of fullcalendar:

```
    eventRender(info) {
      info.el.setAttribute('id', info.event.id);
      let  eventWidth = 0;
      let relX = 0;
      let relY = 0;
      let relOffsetX = 0;

      $( info.el).mouseover(function( event ) { //info.el -> html element
        relX = event.pageX - $(this).offset().left;
        relY = event.pageY - $(this).offset().top;
        eventWidth = document.getElementById(info.event.id).offsetWidth;
        relOffsetX = relX - eventWidth / 2; // not finished but atm nothing is set as offset
        tippy(info.el, {
          content:  `${info.event.extendedProps.listTitle  } / ${   info.event.extendedProps.swimlaneTitle}`,
          offset: relOffsetX,
        });
      });
```

The offset is correctly calculated but it does not work, the tooltip always is in the same positon ignoring the mouse position.

Can someone help?

I would also accept as a alternative solution another Tooltip node or meteor package, which works better.

Comment: Please include the relevant HTML and JS files; not just the snippets.